# Check TextInputEditText in AlertDialog in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-textinputedittext

I wrote this code to set a password in `AlertDialog` but when I click on the button to save the password, it does not check `TextInputEditText` and the dialog is closed. What should I do? (my dialog run in first activity)

```
public class CreatePasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_password);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password_dialog, null);

        final TextInputEditText pass = view.findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
        final TextInputEditText confPass = view.findViewById(R.id.edt_confirm_password);
        final TextInputLayout passLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.password_layout);
        final TextInputLayout confPassLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.confirm_password_layout);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton("ثبت", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        pass.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                if (pass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                    passLayout.setError("رمز عبور را وارد كنيد");
                                } else {
                                    passLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
                                }

                                if (confPass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                    confPassLayout.setError("رمز عبور را مجددا وارد كنيد");
                                } else {
                                    confPassLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .show()
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `if (!pass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                                    //operations
                                } else {
                                            passLayout.setError("missing");
                                            passLayout.requestFocus();
                                }`

Comment: it dosnt work again. after clicking on posetive button, dialog will close and dosnt check empty edittext

Comment: try this `String strUserInput = pass.getText().toString().trim();
                                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserInput)) {

                                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mView, "Name field cannot be left blank", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    snackbar.show();
                                    return;
                                }`

Answer (score 1):

I am now giving a full implementation of the code

layout/dialog.xml (you can have your own UI)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inp1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inp2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="CLICK"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);
        dialog.setContentView(view);

        TextInputLayout layout1 = view.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        TextInputLayout layout2 = view.findViewById(R.id.layout2);

        TextInputEditText inp1 = view.findViewById(R.id.inp1);
        TextInputEditText inp2 = view.findViewById(R.id.inp2);

        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(inp1.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    layout1.setError("fill box one");
                    return;
                }
                if(inp2.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    layout2.setError("fill box two");
                    return;
                }
                // IF BOTH ARE FILLED THEN CLOSE THE DIALOG
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```